# Выборка из таблицы в массив без дублирующих записей

Tags: php, mysql, sql, массивы

Есть такая таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно достать массив товаров, чтобы товар не дублировался и в нем в массиве были *pay* и *devivery*.
Проект на php.

Вот запрос:

```
SELECT t.id,
   t.name,
   p.id AS p_id,
   p.name AS p_name,
   d.id AS d_id,
   d.name AS d_name

FROM tovar t
     LEFT JOIN tovar_to_pay tp ON t.id = tp.id_tovar
     LEFT JOIN pay p ON tp.id_pay = p.id
     LEFT JOIN tovar_to_deliv td ON t.id = td.id_tovar
     LEFT JOIN deliv d ON td.id_deliv = d.id;
```

Вот результат выборки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно товары дублируются.
Менять запрос можно, или же на php сделать скрипт, который все это приведет к нужному результату.

Comment: вы приведите пример нужного результат то? Если нужны просто уникальные пары `p_name, d_name` то так и напишите `select distinct p_name, d_name`

Comment: знаете, тут так не принято, это не фриланс - либо ты пытаешься что-то делать самостоятельно и обращаешься за помощью по конкретной проблеме, либо идёшь куда-то в другое место и платишь деньги чтоб тебе всё сделали под ключ

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы в массиве были все найденные значения из `pay` и `deliv`, или достаточно первого попавшегося? Если нужны все подходящие значения, а не "какое-нибудь из подходящих", то напишите также как запрос выполняете - mysql, mysqli или PDO? Если достаточно одного значения из каждой таблицы - то тогда можно в конце запроса написать `GROUP BY t.id`